# storing multiple data by using $_SESSION array without using database in php

Tags: php, arrays, session

i want to store multiple data by using session array from one page to another......here is my code:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login_status'] = false;

?>
<html>

    <title> Registration  </title>

    <body>

        <form method="post" action="multiple_login.php">

            Name:<input type="text" name="Name"> </br>
            Age:<input type="numeric" name="age"> </br>
            Address: <input type="text" name="add"> </br>
            Email: <input type = "text" name="email"> </br>
            Password: <input type = "password" name="pass"> </br>
            Re-type password: <input type = "password" name="r_pass"> </br>
                   <input type="submit" value="Sign up">



        </form>


    </body>


</html>


<?php





    if($_POST){


        $_SESSION["user"] = array(
        "name" => $_POST["name"],
        "email" => $_POST["email"],
        "password" => $_POST["pass"]
    );

        $_SESSION['login_status'] = false;

            ?>

            <script>
                window.location = "http://localhost/login/m_log.php";
            </script>

            <?php

           // }
    }       
?>
```

what am i supposed to do in m_log.php page for showing multiple names,addresses,ages,emails.. 
for example: frst i give input name1,age1,add1,email1...it will show in the m_log page..and then if i again give input like name2,age2,add2... both name1 and name2 age1 and age2 will be shown in the m_log page...i don't want to use the database...thnx in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, can you clarify?

Comment: How exactly are you going to check a password if you don't have a database? Also, I can you sign up if you don't store the user?

Comment: i want to print all the inputs at a same time untill the session exists like frstly i register with my name address age..and 2nd tym u will register through your bio..then i will print both ur bio and my bio at the same time...

Comment: without database i can't store the pass or anything using session??? @Rasclatt

Comment: You need a persistent storage system like a database otherwise there is nothing to check against, especially if that session expires. All that information is gone and the user has to start over again.

Comment: A session will store what you want but it's not made for permanent storing. Also, there is no way to access someone else's information like a bio or whatever because the session is unique to the computer it's being browsed with

Comment: i need to do it when the sesssion exists..that means as long as the browser is open..i know by using database it's simple...but i want to try it this way @Rasclatt

Comment: Ok. Well, I have a feeling you will waste many hours on it...likely more than the amount of time it would take to learn to use a simple databasing system like `MySQL`. Good luck with it though! Cheers.

Comment: my apologies for the answer, I thought I was answering a different question.

Comment: You can do that with a session if you want your users to register every 30 minutes, or similar

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to make a database for this.
Because sessions are being destroyed once the browser is closed. Thus, making your data only temporary.